# Facebook Targeting Field removed from 'Post' object documentation

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, targeting

Within the documentation for Status and Post there used to be a field called 'targeting'.

See: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/status/ and 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

However, now that 'targeting' field is no longer there. For the Post object, there is now a privacy field which contains targeting.
It still works when I use 'targeting' in the Graph API to create a Post.

Does anyone know if the 'targeting' field is being phased out?